# How to load language with gettext in PHP?

Tags: php, gettext, poedit

I have created a language file in poedit for the use of the PHP gettext function, now on the page I am trying to test it on, I cannot get it to find/load the .po or .mo file I created, does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
$locale = "en_US";
putenv("LC_ALL=$locale");
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
bindtextdomain("default", "/includes/locale");
textdomain("default");

//my .po ad .mo file is located here /includes/locale/en/default.mo
```

Even though I am trying to load the default english lang file, I have changed some text in the file to make sure it is reading from a language file and currently it is only showing the default text and not doing a translation, I think I have the wrong path possibly

Comment: [PHP-I18N](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-I18N) does all that for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally got it to work, I am posting here so maybe it can help someone else, it is somewhat confusing the way it is documented I think.

I will use FR for french for this demo

```
$locale = "fr_fr";
putenv("LC_ALL=$locale");
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
bindtextdomain("default", "/includes/locale");
textdomain("default");
```

In the **`bindtextdomain` function** above, the first param is the name of the .po language file minus the extension.  The second param is the path to the folder, this is where is gets a little tricky/undocumented... In the folder you set here you have to create a folder for each language with it's 2 digit country code, then inside this country code folder I had to add this folder named **`LC_MESSAGES`**, inside `LC_MESSAGES` is where your `default.po` file goes.

This was the only way I could get it to work, kind of confusing since the path to the lang folder does not mention anything about the bold part here:

> langfolder/**fr_FR/LC_MESSAGES**/default.po

It is still really strange though, `default.po` works for me but if I change it to something else in the code above and then change the filename of the .po and .mo files to match it will no longer work, only works with `default` name for me, I am starting to think maybe gettext does some sort of behind the scenes caching

Comment: There is some caching with gettext, so you often have to restart Apache if you change an .mo file.

Comment: this didn't work for me, I've needed to add `.utf8` to `$locale` and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it's your path.

Is "/includes/locale" the correct directory on your host? Or is that relative to something? Note: you need the full pathname, not relative to your home directory or the install directory. so that might be something like:

- C:/xampp/htdocs/include/locale
- /var/www/include/locale
- /home/username/include/locale
- etc

What is the full directory where it's found?

Comment: Yes I just tried that C:\webserver\htdocs\includes\locale is the actual path, I check it in a browser and that loads but it doesn't help with the gettext, it is weird I had a small demo that works fine without the full path but it has a bunch of weird directory names maybe they are required, can't find a lot of info on php.net about it though

Comment: Use forward slashes not backslashes. Even though Windows is \, put it in like I did with /

Comment: what confuses me is the bindtextdomain and textdomain functions, a domain, I think of site.com but here I think it means something different