# How to use gettext on linux in php?

Tags: php, gettext

I've follow instructions from [How to load language with gettext in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450037/how-to-load-language-with-gettext-in-php)

I've created ./locale/pl_PL/LC_MESSAGES/default.po file with:

```
msgid "categories"
msgstr "kategorie"
```

I've generated mo file using:

```
msgfmt default.po -o default.mo
```

and I have code like this:

```
    $lang = 'pl_PL';
    $this->root = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    echo $lang . "\n" . $this->root . "locale\n";
    putenv("LC_ALL=$lang");
    setlocale(LC_ALL, $lang);
    bindtextdomain("default", $this->root . "locale");
    textdomain("default");

    echo _("categories");
```

but I've got untranslated text, the output is:

```
pl_PL
/home/kuba/projects/jcubic/cataloger/locale
categories
```

I've also tried to use slash at the end of locale but that didn't help.

What's wrong? How can I use gettext to translate text? I'm running php from apache 2 on GNU/Linux. I'm using slim and twig frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

I've needed to add `.utf8` to the locale (so it's `pl_PL.utf8`) and it work.